# New to Coding: Iterating over a list in Python

Tags: python

So I am completely new to coding and I'm going through a class right now and I'm stuck. Essentially the problem is this:

Assign `sum_extra` with the total extra credit received given list `test_grades`. Full credit is 100, so anything over 100 is extra credit.

Sample output for the given program with input: '101 83 107 90'

My current code is this:

```
user_input = input()
test_grades = list(map(int, user_input.split())) # test_grades is an integer list of test scores


sum_extra = 0 

for grade in test_grades: 
    if grade > 100:
        sum_extra = grade - 100
        
print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```

The problem I am having is that it isn't adding the total extra over 100. Like for the example inputs above it runs and totals 7 instead of 8. I'm honestly not sure what I am missing. Also if it isn't too much trouble, I would prefer to just get a nudge in the right direction rather than a flat out answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to add to previous value of `sum_extra`. right now you are overwriting it.

Comment: Also, it is a good practice to give a prompt when asking user input. `user_input = input("Enter the grades")`

Comment: ```sum_extra+=(int(user_input)-100)```. This will add the value to ```sum_extra```

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions and help. It really helped out.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum_extra = grade - 100
```

That line of code assigns a *new* value to sum_extra, discarding whatever value it already had.

Instead, you want to *add* to the existing value:

```
sum_extra = sum_extra + (grade - 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum_extra` needs to contain the *sum* of all the extra points. As written your code overwrites it with the current excess each time rather than adding together all the extra points.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating through the test_grades list, if grade is greater than 100 then you need to update the sum_extra i.e. `sum_extra += grade - 100`

So the exact code will be like this

```py
user_input = input()
test_grades = list(map(int, user_input.split())) # test_grades is an integer list of test scores


sum_extra = 0 

for grade in test_grades: 
    if grade > 100:
        sum_extra += grade - 100
        
print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following statement, `sum_extra = grade - 100`, you are updating sum_extra value. To get the sum of the extra credits you need to accumulate by doing the following: `sum_extra += (grade - 100)`.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, but similar answer is already posted by someone. You should only post an answer if it is different from others' answers.